# How to reverse sort the output from grep -rc

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, sort

I want to be able to sort the output from the `grep -rc` command,

I am currently using the command:

```
grep -rc "Pattern" . | sort -t: -rk2,2n
```

however the list is still sorted from low to high, instead of high to low...
it also prints out the exact output when using:

```
grep -rc "Pattern" . | sort -t: -k2,2n
```

So what I want is for the outputs:

```
data_x:12 
data_y:34
data_z:56
data_a:205
data_b:1003
```

to be sorted into

```
data_b:1003
data_a:205
data_z:56
data_y:34
data_x:12
```

Comment: Try `grep -rc "Pattern" . | sort -t: -k2,2rn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there except you need the `r` modifier do a reverse sort:

```
grep -rc "Pattern" . | sort -t: -k2,2nr
```

check the `r` modifier after `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
~]# cat test
 data_x:12
 data_y:34
 data_z:56
 data_a:205
 data_b:1003

~]# sort -k2 -n -r -t: test
 data_b:1003
 data_a:205
 data_z:56
 data_y:34
 data_x:12
```

So for your code, you can do

```
~]# grep -rc "Pattern" . | sort -k2 -n -r -t:
```